# How to convert comma separated value into rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

> How can I convert comma separated value as :

**Table**

```
User Name  Unit
ABC        2,3
```

to the following :

```
User Name  Unit
ABC        2  
ABC        3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: which database version?

Comment: Azure Sql server 2016

Comment: Can you please check if 2016 inbuilt support split function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have tagged your question with SQL Server 2016, in SQL Server 2016 there is a new function [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).

In SQL Server 2016 your query should be as simple as:

```
declare @tab table ([user_name] varchar(10),Unit varchar(100))
insert into @tab
VALUES ('ABC','1,2')

SELECT t.[user_name]
       , Value as Unit
FROM @tab t 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Unit , ',')
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL server below will be the logic Hope it helps

```
declare @tab table ([user_name] varchar(10),val varchar(100))
insert into @tab
select 'ABC','1,2'

SELECT A.[user_name],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [user_name],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(val, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  @tab) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

output

```
user_name   String
ABC          1
ABC          2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitCSVs (@CSVString varchar(1000))

RETURNS @SeparatedValues TABLE (Value VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @CommaPosition INT
 WHILE (CHARINDEX(',', @CSVString, 0) > 0)
 BEGIN
  SET @CommaPosition = CHARINDEX(',', @CSVString, 0)
  INSERT INTO @SeparatedValues (Value)
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@CSVString, 0, @CommaPosition)
  SET @CSVString = STUFF(@CSVString, 1, @CommaPosition, '')
 END
  INSERT INTO @SeparatedValues (Value)
  SELECT @CSVString

 RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitCSVs('aby,123')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52400332/4733879) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: Welcome! Please note that [overt self-promotion is not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `fn_split` function.

Comment: Please add explanation around your answer